# Sonic Pi control

Tags: gpio

I would like to control Sonic Pi via the Rasberry Pi GPIO pins.
For example if a pin goes high, a tone starts playing.
It appears that Sonic Pi can only be controlled on the local machine using OSC commands.

1. is this the only option?
2. is a background Python script that polls the GPIO pins and then sends a OSC command, the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: Isn't this question about "Sonic Pi", and not really about "Raspberry Pi"??

Comment: Sorry, first time i’ve ever used this forum. It is Sonic Pi running on a Raspberry Pi. Not sure if there is a more accurate subject/tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the necessary libraries  for both Sonic Pi and GPIO control in Python. You can use the python-osc library for sending OSC messages from Python.
You can write the following python script  to send an OSC message to Sonic Pi.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from pythonosc import udp_client

# Set up GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(<your_pin_number>, GPIO.IN)

# Set up OSC client
client = udp_client.SimpleUDPClient("127.0.0.1", 4557)  # Sonic Pi's default OSC address

def callback(channel):
    if GPIO.input(channel):
        # GPIO pin is high, send OSC message
        client.send_message("/play", "<your_sound_command>")

# Add event listener
GPIO.add_event_detect(<your_pin_number>, GPIO.BOTH, callback=callback)

try:
    while True:
        pass  # Keep the script running

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```